# Questions re ufw settings

Tags: networking, firewall, ufw

I have been running Ubuntu 20.04 desktop since last February, and I configured and enabled ufw at that time.  I have questions on the output below.

```
sudo ufw numbered

To                                   Action  From

[ 1] Anywhere               ALLOW IN    192.168.0.0/24
[ 2] 80/tcp                 ALLOW IN    Anywhere
[ 3] 443/tcp                ALLOW IN    Anywhere
[ 4] Samba                  ALLOW IN    Anywhere
[ 5] 80/tcp (v6)            ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
[ 6] 443/tcp (v6)           ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
[ 7] Samba (v6)             ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
```

My questions are:

1. What does “Anywhere” mean in the “To” column of rule #1 and what does rule #1 control?  I have the list of well-known ports and port 24 is not listed. What is it used for?
2. Are there any rules defined above that are not advised?
3. Are there any other rules I should include?

Thanks very much.

Comment: 24 is not a port. It is a range of IP addresses.  See https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/subnet-cheat-sheet-24-subnet-mask-30-26-27-29-and-other-ip-address-cidr-network-references/ Rule 1 means any IP address in that range can access any port on this system.

Comment: No one can answer questions 2 and 3 except for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> (1) What does “Anywhere” mean in the “To” column of rule #1 and what does rule #1 control? I have the list of well-known ports and port 24 is not listed. What is it used for?

The /24 is called a "[slash notation](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/subnet-cheat-sheet-24-subnet-mask-30-26-27-29-and-other-ip-address-cidr-network-references/)" refers to subnetmask 255.255.255.0. In total it refers to a range of 254 usable IP addresses. And "anywhere" means those IP addresses allow incoming traffic to "anywhere" on the local network.

> (2) Are there any rules defined above that are not advised?

Anything Windows related could be considered a security threat. So that includes samba. ssh with private keys is a lot more secure.

> (3) Are there any other rules I should include?

That depends on software used. Mind that I never ever had to use firewall rules on my desktop. No idea why you would need them. On a server yes. Desktop not so much. Ubuntu is secure out of the box.

Comment: Wouldn't *“Anywhere” [mean] in the “To” column* in an `ALLOW IN` rule mean **to** any port and interface on the local machine? if it means *allow incoming traffic from "anywhere"*, why does the the "From" column say `192.168.0.0/24`?

Comment: This answer is incorrect. The /24 does not mean 24 IP addresses, it means 254 IP addresses. See the link in my earlier comment for an explanation. And it does not mean the addresses allow traffic to them, it means traffic is allowed from those addresses.

Comment: sorry was too much distracted when I posted this. ill edit it